# Shortcuts to favorite stack sites

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, linked-accounts, icons

Hi,

I am currently active on 4 Stack sites, and to switch I click on the "StackExchange" button, click on "all Sites", scroll until the site I look for appears, mostly at the bottom of the list, and then click the site. Very annoying.

Since you alreay know the accounts one is connected with, why don't you let us choose which we want to have linked on the start page? I would love an small 16px icon for each site I use regulary at the right of the "StackExchange" dropdown. Maybe You could just add some checkboxes in the preferences page where one could select the sites one needs, so not all my sites appear, but just the 4 I would check.

This would make it more comfortable to have a quick look at the other sites and answer questions there... currently is switching just annoying, and so I just stay on StackOverflow.

PS: I know I could bookmark each site, but I often switch the clients I use, and don't want to have to create bookmarks on all these sites, when usually a quick "stacko" in googles search field is enough to get here.

Comment: The sites in the dropdown should be ordered by your reputation. Are the sites you're interested in ones you don't have much rep in, or are they not being sorted by rep?

Comment: @waiwai: Just a guess, but I think they're partially sorted by rep. I have SO (6k) and SF (200-something) at the top, but SU (108 I think) is down near the bottom, so maybe it's sorted for sites with > 200 rep or something, then just random(?).

Comment: Yes, Superuser is always at the bottom, and this has my third-most rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now **sort the gen-u-wine sites list by the amount of reputation you have on each site.**

[image]

You must have a minimum of **200 rep** on any given site to have it appear in anything other than random order, though.

Comment: So... was it sorting before or not? Also, why impose a minimum rep for the sorting? Just curious if nothing else.

Comment: @jon it's been sorting for quite a while, but not everyone has figured that out yet