# Extend the StackExchange menu with "mySites"

Tags: feature-request

Sorry for this bad title but I don't know how to name it right. I registered my account now to about six other sites of the Network and wondered if I can easy switch between the sites without any need of URL typing. I was looking for a menu where all "MySites" are listed, something like this:

[image]

I hope this is no duplicate. I found nothing from the search about this.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if you're logged in, the "all sites" tab is automatically ordered so that sites that you have the most reputation on appear first. Therefore, the sites you're signed up on appear at the top.

Comment: very related, almost dupe? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81928/shortcuts-to-favorite-stack-sites

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As soon as you have more that 200 in the associated account of that site, it is coming first. The next ones (below 200) are random.

This has been asked before I'm sure.

Comment: OK, I did not realized that and I did not found that question with the search. Nevertheless I don't think that this is intuitive. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: I agree with this person, I'm a new user with low rep, and it's annoying to try and find the right site, could you not collect some small heuristic of usage statistics to base the order on?
Basing it on rep seems silly to me; it should be based on views.